# Queue for transfer doesn't include contents within folder

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

In my Umbraco cloud instance I can't see option to include contents within any child folder while using option "Queue for transfer". I can do this with home folder(top folder). See below screenshot.

[image]

Not sure if this is a temporary bug in cloud instance or there is any option I am missing. Can any one suggest if there is any option to transfer, content in chunk for child folders?

Comment: After talking to cloud support team, I learnt that there is some issue with Umbraco cloud and this issue is already reported here http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/UAAS-548. But, I'll still wait for some response from community if anyone have any work around.

Answer (score 0):

So, further chasing the issue with Umbraco cloud support, I found that it is a know issue with Umbraco cloud and for document type configured to show as list view. The work around for this issue is to disable the list view for document type.